# Hiding modal in react

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I need some help with hiding my modal. On my button onclick I'm running the built in `showModal()` function which opens up my popup window. Since `showModal()` already existed I assumed there would be a similar built in function like `hideModal()`.

The window will close if I press the escape key so I'm wondering what happens when I press ESC. This is my function for displaying it:

```
modal(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("myDialog").showModal(); 
}
```

And here is the element im trying to show/hide:

```
   <dialog id="myDialog">
    Namn:
    <input className="modalInput" /><br />
    Ålder:
    <input className="modalInput" /><br />
    Ras:
    <input className="modalInput" /><br />
    Beskrivning:
    <textarea /><br />

    <button className="confirmBooking" onClick=
    {this.bookingBtn}>Boka</button>
    <button className="closeModal" onClick={this.closeModal}>X</button><br 
     />
    {this.state.bokning} 



    </dialog>
```

Comment: easy, try with close()

 onClick={this.close()}

but this button must be INSIDE modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, I forgot this was not angular. Edited: This is in pure html, dialog option, you can use it like a modal:

Here you have a simple example of how to open and close a modal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to show the dialog.</p>

<button onclick="openthis()">Show dialog</button>

<p><b>Note:</b> Use the "Esc" button to close the modal.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The dialog element is only supported in Chrome 37+, Safari 6+ and Opera 24+.</p>

<dialog id="myDialog">This is a dialog window
<button onclick="closethis()">close dialog</button>
</dialog>

<script>
function openthis() { 
    document.getElementById("myDialog").showModal(); 
} 

function closethis() { 
    document.getElementById("myDialog").close(); 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Copy-paste into a new.html and check.
Hope this helps

[also here´s a fiddle in react showing how to show and hide a div](http://jsfiddle.net/janklimo/dy34twvk/) --from user @jan klimo.

Comment: $scope.closeModal= function() {
                $scope.modal.hide();                
            }

Is this jquery? I'm trying to do this in react so im not sure it will work in that case. Thanks for the reply

Comment: OP is not looking for angularjs answer.

Comment: @smuckert no sorry, $scope.modal.hide() is angularjs, I misread your question thinking of "modal views" in angular, sorry.

Comment: document.getElementById("myDialog").close(); worked for me, thanks alot!